# Necessary and sufficient conditions for a product of norms to be the square of a norm

Tags: normed-spaces, triangle-inequality

Let $(E,N)$ be a normed space, and $M$ be another norm. Can you find a necessary and sufficient condition on $M$ so that $\sqrt{NM}$ is also a norm on $E$?

I hink the condition is that $M$ is proportional to $N$.

Of course, the only thing to investigate is the triangle inequality: we want to prove that if for all $x, y \in E$ there holds
$$
\sqrt{N(x+y)M(x+y)} \leq \sqrt{N(x)M(x)} + \sqrt{N(y)M(y)}
$$
then there is $\lambda >0$ such that $M=\lambda N$.

Does anoyone know?

I tried to prove a "reverse" triangle inequality without success:
$$
N(x+y)M(x+y) \geq (N(x)-N(y))(M(x)-M(y)) = N(x)M(x)+N(y)M(y) - N(x)M(y)-M(x)N(y)
$$
wheras $(\sqrt{N(x)M(x)} + \sqrt{N(y)M(y)})^2 = N(x)M(x) + N(y)M(y) +2\sqrt{N(x)M(x)N(y)M(y)}$ resembles it, but I'm unable to finish.

EDIT: I tried (assuming that $\sqrt{NM}$ is a norm) that for all $x, y \in E$ there holds $(\sqrt{N(x)M(y)} - \sqrt{N(y)M(x)})^2 \leq 0$, which then shows that $N$ and $M$ are proportional.